# Return value from ObservableArrayList instantiated from fxml not as expected

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I'm trying to pass a variable list of strings into a custom controller in fxml, thus:

```
<Pane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
   <VBox fx:id="vbox">
      <StepChart fx:id="employment"   title="Unemployment" enabled = "true"  prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="300.0">
          <statistics>
             <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList" >
                 <String fx:value="employees"/>
                 <String fx:value="farms"/>
             </FXCollections>
           </statistics>
       </StepChart>
     </VBox>
  </Pane>
```

statistics is labelled as an @DefaultProperty in StepChart, but included here for completeness. In StepChart I'm picking up the observable list values as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ObservableList<String> statistics = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);

statistics.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>()
  {
     @Override
     public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> change)
     {         
        for(String s: statistics)
        {
           System.out.println("s: " +  s);
        }
     }
  });
```

Which all works perfectly, except that rather than a list of separate strings, the fxml is generating a single string, with the fxml values in it:

```
s: [employees, farms]
```

even though [Introduction to fxml](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html)  says that it "creates an instance of an observable array list, populated with three string values". Am I missing something about how to handle the observablelist, or is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Does `StepChart` have a `setStatistics(List<String>)` method, or just a `getStatistics()`?

Comment: urgh. That was it - many thanks.

Comment: You don't need a `setStatistics(...)` method if it doesn't make sense for your `StepChart` class to have one. I'll put everything together as an actual answer, as either way others may benefit from this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your `StepChart` class doesn't have a `setStatistics(...)` method. The `FXMLLoader` will treat this in a special way, as follows:

Normally, when the `FXMLLoader` encounters a structure like:

```
<ClassName fx:id="ref">
  <propertyName>
     <AnotherClass />
  </propertyName>
</ClassName>
```

it executes code that translates to something like:

```
ClassName ref = new ClassName();
ref.setPropertyName(new AnotherClass());
```

(not literally, it does the equivalent but using reflection).

For the most part, if there is no `setPropertyName(...)` defined in the specified class, an exception will be thrown.

Read-only lists are treated as a special case: so if `ClassName` defines a `List getList() {...}` method, and no `void setList(List aList) {...}` method, then the following still works:

```
<ClassName fx:id="ref">
   <list>
      <!-- values -->
   </list>
</ClassName>
```

The way this is handled, in this particular case (the name of the property corresponds to a property of type `List` with a `get` method and no `set` method), then the `FXMLLoader` executes the following pseudocode:

```
ClassName ref = new ClassName();
for (Object item : itemsDefinedInsideListElement) {
    ref.getList().add(item);
}
```

where the `for` loop iterates over all the elements defined inside the `<list>` element. The is what enables you to do things like

```
<HBox>
  <children>
    <Label/>
    <TextField/>
  </children>
</HBox>
```

even though `HBox` has no `setChildren()` method.

So, with your FXML, assuming `StepChart` has no `setStatistics(...)` method, the `FXMLLoader` iterates over all the direct child elements of `<statistics>`, passing each one to `getStatistics().add(...)` invoked on the `StepChart` instance it created. In this case, there is only one child element, which is an `ObservableList<String>`.

The `FXMLLoader` is also smart enough to figure the generic type of the list at runtime (I actually have no idea how it does this). Since it sees the list is expecting a `String`, and the element did not resolve to a `String`, it attempts to coerce it to the correct type. Coercing to a `String` is easy: it merely calls `toString` on the result of creating the list, and passes the result in. So you end up with a list that contains a single `String`: that `String` is the result of calling `toString` on a `List` containing the elements "employees" and "farms". The equivalent Java code would look something like

```
StepChart employment = new StepChart();
employment.getStatistics().add(Arrays.asList("employees", "farms").toString());
```

and so you see the single element `"["employees", "farms"]"` as the contents of `statistics`.

You have two fixes for this, and the one you choose should depend on what API you want to expose in `StepChart`. You can either add in a `setStatistics(ObservableList<String>)` method. Then the `FXMLLoader` will create the list, and pass it into that method.

Alternatively, you can continue to omit the `setStatistics(...)` method (i.e. keep `statistics` as a read-only list property) and modify the FXML to

```
  <StepChart fx:id="employment"  ... >
      <statistics>
         <String fx:value="employees"/>
         <String fx:value="farms"/>
       </statistics>
   </StepChart>
```

so that you use the `FXMLLoader`'s read-only list property mechanism.

Comment: That's a very useful explanation - thanks. It's really helpful knowing how it fits together - I find there's a certain element of voodoo in some of the online documentation. (I had at the back of my mind the thought that it looked like it was trying to coerce it, but didn't know how - but hadn't made the connection with the beans-like semantics.)

Comment: I agree: in general the documentation for what the `FXMLLoader` does is pretty woeful. There is a [request for enhancement](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35522) for this for which you might like to vote. This particular topic is covered to some extent in the [Introduction to FXML document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#property_setter_elements).

Comment: But, but.. I like slaughtering goats at midnight :) duly voted.